# Post request with nested json object react axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a post request with nested abject but I got `Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0` error. Here is my Code.

```
const submit = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        `baseUrl/api/birthCertificate/register`,
        {
          birthCertificate: {
            first_name: "abebe",
            middle_name: "kebede",
            last_name: "kebede",
            date_of_birth: "1998-10-10",
            gender: "male",
            nationality: "22",
            phone_number: "0987654321",
            email: "user27@gmail.com",
            birth_place: {
              country: "chad",
              province: "",
              subProvince: "",
              birthType: "hospital",
              hospitalName: "chad hospital",
            },
            fullNameOfFather: "father full name",
            fullNameOfMother: "mother full name",
            nationalityOfFather: "22",
            nationalityOfMother: "22",
            idCardImage: "idCardImage",
            personImage: "personImage",
            userAddress: {
              region: "Addis Ababa",
              city: "Addis Ababa",
              state: "Addis",
              zone: "02",
              street: "green-street",
              house_number: ".232",
            },
          },
        }
      )
      .then(
        (response) => {
          alert("success");
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  };
```

Is there any other implementation for making this post request with multiple object to make successful post request?

Thanks

Comment: Have you used correct template literals in the url?
It should be `${baseUrl}/${api}/birthCertificate/register`

Answer (score 0):

JSON object requires double quotes around keys and make sure to add content type header